# I want to make an infinite input and end it when user input 0. After that I want to find the maximum number

Tags: python

I tried this code

```py
while True:
    y = input("")
    if y== '0':
        break

max_number = max(y)
print(max_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could just use `max` on an iterator over the inputs:

```
print(max(iter(input, '0'), key=int))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this

```
ys = []

while True:
    y = input("")
    if y== '0':
        break
    else:
        ys.append(y)

max_number = max(ys)
print(max_number)
```

Comment: Finds the max string, not necessarily the max number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is that you're treating the `input` as a `string`. In order to calculate the maximum number, you can convert the input to an `integer` (or float if you wish), then use the `max()` function.

```
ys = []
while True:
    y = int(input())
    if y == 0:
        break
    else:
        ys.append(y)
```

Note that the first input can be 0, so it will raise an error if you try to calculate the maximum value of an empty list. You can add a conditional to avoid that.

```
max_number = max(ys) if ys else None
print(max_number)
```